# Beamer change section numbering halfway the presentation from number to letters

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

I'd like to have my beamer presentation split in half:
first half with lettering as sections, so like

> 1. Introduction
> 2. Content 1...

Then the last sections I'd like to have an appendix with letters as numbering of sections, like

> A. Appendix 1
>
> B. List of tables

how can I accomplish this halfway through the presentation?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code of what you're trying to do and what you have tried. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that .

Comment: Please add a minimal working example so we can see which theme etc. you use

Comment: Use command `\appendix` for that.